# Is there any Android XML documentation?

Tags: xml, android, api, reference

Is there any sort of xml reference?

I found this which turned out to be invaluable for me

- [(Multiple) Shape drawing with XML](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/d334017d72909c79)

But I can't figure out how I was supposed to know how to do that, had
I not found that post.

I know that the api reference has xml attributes listed for many of
the classes... but what about xml tags? Where is it documented that I
could build a shape using `<padding>`, `<corners>`, `<solid>` tags?

I'd really like to know where I can find such documentation.

Comment: that should have said "could build a shape using &lt;padding&gt;, &lt;corners&gt;, &lt;solid&gt;

Comment: D'oh. "Add Comment" wouldn't let me preview. Here we go again:
Should be: "Where is it documented that I
could build a shape using <padding>, <corners>, <solid> tags?"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The classes which have XML attributes, list them XML attributes in their own documentation. Attributes beginning with layout are documented in the containing layout class.

The [manifest file is documented here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html). Google recently added a lot of new documentation, including documentation on [XML resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html). See this webpage on [drawable resources](http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html).

There resources aren't comprehensive, so [R.styleable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html) is still often the best bet. [R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) is better if you just want to see all attributes, rather than the attributes available for a particular tag.

Comment: The web page documenting drawable resources is now obsolete. XML resources are now well documented.

Answer (score 8):

While you're editing the Android XML files in Eclipse, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to retrieve a list of optional tags that are currently allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a (200-page) start:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html

Answer (score 3):

I've wondered this several times too. Best I can figure there isn't any real documentation on this stuff.

I've mostly been just going through the source the SDK gives us so that I could figure out how they did it. The files in `$SDK_PATH/platforms/android-1.5/data/res/` should show you how pretty much everything was done for the base system. It isn't easy and it isn't documentation, but it IS examples.

Answer (score 2):

In the specific View documentation you can find the XML attributes.

Quoting Android reference:

> "The best place to find properties that apply to a specific `View` is
>   the **corresponding class reference**, which **lists all of the supported
>   XML attributes**. For example, all of the attributes listed in the table
>   of `TextView XML attributes` can be used in a style definition for a
>   TextView element (or one of its subclasses).
>
> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Tip: Look at the Summary of the object's documentation (at the top) and click on `XML Attrs` to jump directly to the XML attributes.

And for a complete list of properties: [R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html)