# Is there an Android XML reference?

Tags: java, xml, android

I'm learning to develop applications for Android but I need to know the XML tags to get my programs to work. They are documented in the javadoc but I would prefer a quick reference.

EDIT: I was talking about the Android GUI XML-files, sorry that I didn't make this clear.

Comment: Similar to: ["Is there any Android XML documentation?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360134/is-there-any-android-xml-documentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah sure, just start reading the Developers Guide [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

You may find helpful [DroiDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/)

Comment: I don't think he was asking about the manifest.xml.  I think he was asking about the xml files to define the UI.  DroidDraw is a good suggestion.

Comment: Thx, DroidDraw is very helpful to learn the XML tags but I'm still searching for a quick referemce/cheat cheet ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can browse the samples app there : http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/index.html

Or you can use the Android Eclipse Plugin that offers a graphical editor for the AndroidManifest.xml file. With this plugin, it's easy to import those samples into your workspace which can be handier to browse through. Just follow the explanations on the previous link.

HTH,

--
Hubert

Comment: I don't think he was asking about the manifest.xml.  I think he was asking about the xml files to define the UI.

Comment: Thx for your answer but the samples are not very helpfull for my UI design problems ;-)
But I'll install eclipse again to try out it's XML editor.
(atm I use NetBeans)