# Android XML Layout Guide

Tags: xml, android, layout

The XML documentation for layouts isn't very good. There are a large number of related variables and it isn't clear at all how they interact or differ. Is there any guide - maybe a book, or blog post ect that would help me understand this?

**Related**

- [Is there any Android XML documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360134/is-there-any-android-xml-documentation)

Answer (score 3):

There are certainly a lot of [books written about Android](http://wiki.andmob.org/books), including some by me. Whether they will answer your questions is unclear.