# Is there an android tag/attribute reference?

Tags: android, reference

I've had some experience with web development, and I found the W3C pages on different tags and attributes to be very useful. 
Is there an equivalent online reference for Android tags and attributes? By Android tags I mean stuff like `<EditText>`, and by android attributes I mean stuff like `android:id`.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2901782/983741

Comment: What about Android developer documentation itself?